# How to check if the line exist by ansible playbook

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, centos

I have file name test

```
cat test
[tag1]
```

I want to add lines after [tag1] in test I find this solution

```
- ini_file:
    path: test
    section: "{{ item.section }}"
    option: "{{ item.option }}"
    allow_no_value: yes
  loop:
    - section: 'tag1'
      option: '# This is line 1'
    - section: 'tag1'
      option: '# This is line 2'
```

But if the line exists I want to do nothing and if does not exist add them.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Cat the file and register the output. Then perform the task if 'string' is not present in the file.

```
- shell: cat test
  register: check
  changed_when: false

- ini_file:
    path: test
    section: "{{ item.section }}"
    option: "{{ item.option }}"
    allow_no_value: yes
  when: '# This is line 1' not in check.stdout
  loop:
    - section: 'tag1'
      option: '# This is line 1'
    - section: 'tag1'
      option: '# This is line 2'
```